# Error is occurring setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, dataframe

I have the columns in my Data Frame as shown below:

```
 Venue             city                Venue Categories

  Madison         London      [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...,0,0]
  WaterFront      Austria     [0, 1, 1 0, 0, 0,  0, ....0,1]
  Aeronaut        Marvilles   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, ....1,1]
  Aeronaut        Paris       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....1,1]
  Gostrich        New York    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....1,0]
```

I am passing this data to my machine learning model , but `model.fit` is not accepting the input , My code is shown below , that I am trying ,

```
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
dff['Venue']=labelencoder.fit_transform(dff['Venue'])
dff['city']=labelencoder.fit_transform(dff['city'])
```

Let's say , if I want to increase the number of features . I want to add more columns , then I again write everything for each feature just like shown below , if i want to add `type` column and `owner` column

```
city = dff['city'].values
owner = dff['owner'].values
type = dff['type'].values
categories = dff['Venue Categories'].values
labels = np.array(dff['Venue'].values)
data = np.array([make_sample(city[i], owner[i], type[i] categories[i]) for i in range(len(city))])
```

This will looks weird , I want to make it global , means there should not need to touch the code if we may increase the number of columns .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work, by combining the `city` column with the `venue categories` column into a `2D` (numpy) array which can be used by the `RandomForestClassifier` of `sklearn`.

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

def make_data(df, target_column='Venue', categories_column='Venue Categories'):
    categories = df[categories_column].values
    other_features = []
    for col in df.columns:
        if col in [categories_column, target_column]: continue
        other_features.append(df[col].values);
    return np.array([[col[i] for col in other_features]+categories[i] for i in range(len(categories))]), np.array(df[target_column].values)

labelencoder = LabelEncoder()

dff['Venue'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(dff['Venue'])
dff['city'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(dff['city'])

data, labels = make_data(dff, 'Venue', 'Venue Categories')

train_data,test_data,train_labels,test_labels = train_test_split(data,labels,test_size=0.20)

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(train_data,train_labels)
```

**Note** make sure that `Venue Categories` column has same number of elements for each row of data, else a new problem will arise again. If needed fill with dummy values

Comment: ok will check it and get back to you

Comment: I think , it is the issue of some tensor , or something else , you may run the code on your side , if it works for you then share with me

Comment: see working example in updated answer. Managed to make it work by combining and converting `city` and `venue categories` into a 2D array suitable for `RandomForestClassifier`

Comment: Well , it is working , can you make it as a global . Means whenever any new column comes , it will auto convert into 2d array not by specifying every time for columns .

Comment: It is concatenating , means data has [4,1,0,1,..] . 4 specify city and next elements an array of categories . Don't you think that it should comes like [4,[1,0,1,1...]] . 4 should comes seperately

Comment: No the data that will be used as input to sklearn classifiers need to be 2d arrays of numbers not nested lists, it wont work. So the solution is to flatten the data into 2d form by combining the values. it is easy to generate one sample by taking the array of categories and prepend the city label into the array, simple as that

Comment: I added a function to combine the features into a single sample

Comment: city and categories have exactly same number of rows, it doesnt matter which one is used to get the indices for the loop

Comment: Please update your question on how new columns are going to be added (and where the venue categories column is going to be, since this is the problematic one) and I can then update my answer

Comment: I have edited , I think now you can get it

Comment: Done see updated answer, in case your target column or categoris column change names simply provide the column names as parameters, else use as is by default

Comment: Thank you very much !